# Discontinuous functions with finite Fourier series approximation?

Tags: continuity, fourier-series

Yesterday I posted a question regarding the computation of complex Fourier coefficients for the functions

$$f(t) = \sin(2 \pi t)$$
$$f(t) = |\sin(2 \pi t)|$$

where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

The first function can easily be represented as a finite sum with Fourier coefficients $c_{-1} = -1/2i$ and $c_1 = 1/2i$.  However, the second function is not smooth at $t = 1/2$ and I was then informed that because of this, the Fourier series will be infinite.

I thus wanted to post the general question:

> Do there exist any discontinuous functions that can be represented by a finite Fourier series?

My intuition says no, but does anyone have a link to a proof for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second function isn't discontinuous at $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @GitGud: Yeah, you're right.  Sorry, I meant to say that it is not smooth.  I will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finite sum of trig functions is not only continuous but $C^\infty$: infinitely smoothly differentiable. So any kind of discontinuity in any derivative results in an infinite sum. Even if 9th derivative is discontinuous!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it!